# Manually dispatch a Django Class Based View

Tags: django

My application is very simple, it has a WeekArchiveView class based view:

```
class MenuWeekArchiveView(WeekArchiveView):
    queryset = Menu.objects.all()
```

And its corresponding URL:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/week/(?P<week>[0-9]+)/$', menu.views.MenuWeekArchiveView.as_view(), name="menu_week"),
```

I would like to have the home page of my application return the current week.

With old function based views, this was easy. I'd just have the home page return that function with the current week number as the arguments.

```
today = datetime.date.today()
current_week_number = today.isocalendar()[1]
current_year = today.year
return week_view(request, year=current_year, week=current_week_number)
```

A redirect wouldn't be acceptable because when someone bookmarks the page, they'll be bookmarking that week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View.as_view()` returns a proper view function you can use:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
current_week_number = today.isocalendar()[1]
current_year = today.year
return MenuWeekArchiveView.as_view()(request, year=current_year, week=current_week_number)
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this while troubleshooting, but got:

    view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @Ben174 that sounds as if you forgot to include the `request` argument.

Comment: I totally did! Did you ninja-edit that in? ;-)  Thanks so much for the help, works perfectly now! I'll accept his answer when it allows me to.

Comment: @Ben174 Yeah, I forgot the request as well :P